# Audio not playing in background

Tags: html, github, audio, deployment, netlify

I am using a simple html to play audio once the page load.

```
<audio src="music/music.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></audio>
```

It works fine when I load my app locally but once I deploy it to github or netlify my audio is not playing, rest of the code works fine.

Comment: You must include the errors you read in console

Comment: There are no errors

Comment: No errors? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Please try source tag inside audio tag. Add 'src' attribute in source tag
This is the valid html syntax

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls loop autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```